# Prove that for any polynomial p with p(x)>0 for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists \alpha > 0$ s.t. $p(x)>\alpha \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that for any polynomial p with $p(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $  \exists    \alpha > 0$   s.t.   $p(x)>\alpha    \forall    x \in \mathbb{R}$

So I've tried this a number of different ways.
First, we know that p is continuous on the real line as it is a polynomial. 
I tried setting $\varepsilon$ as various things in the definition of continuity but nothing seemed to work. I also tried using the definition of sequential continuity but that didn't seem to work either.

Could someone guide me please?

Comment: For a continuous function, the proposition is false. For example, consider $f(x)=e^x$. So the function being polynomial is crucial to prove it.

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ is a constant this is obvious. Let $p(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k x^{k}$, $a_N \neq 0$. Suppose $N$ is odd.  Then $p(x) \to -\infty $ as $x \to \infty$ or as $x \to -\infty$ according as $a_N <0$ or $a_N>0$. Since $p$ is positive it follows that $N$ must be even. Now there exists $T$ such that $p(x) >1$ for all $x$ with $|x| >T$. On $[-T,T]$ the continuous function $p$ has a minimum (which must be positive). The rest should now be clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this by contradiction. First of all, let's write what we are trying to prove:

$$\exists \alpha > 0: \forall x\in\mathbb R: p(x)>\alpha$$

Now, assume the opposite, which is:

$$\forall \alpha > 0 \exists x\in\mathbb R: p(x) < \alpha$$

Now, construct a sequence. First, find $x_1$ such that $p(x_1)<\alpha$. Now, find $x_2$ such that $p(x_2)<\frac{1}{2}$. We can in this way fins a sequence such that $p(x_i)<\frac{1}{i}$.

Now, since we know that $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} p(x) = \infty,$$ (because the limit, for polynomials, can only ever be $\infty$ or $-\infty$) we can conclude that the sequence of $x_i$ is bounded, and therefore has a convergent subsequence $y_i$, and for this subsequence, we also have $p(y_i)<\frac{1}{i}$ (because $y_i=x_j$ for some $j\geq i$, and $p(x_j)<\frac{1}{j}\leq \frac{1}{i}$). But this means that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} p(y_n) = 0$$

On the other hand, $p$ is continuous, so

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} p(y_n) = p(\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n)$$

which means that $p(\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n) = 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: How do you assure that $x_i$ converges?

Comment: @5xum Some additional argument is necessary when $x_i \to \pm \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(0)=:c>0$. If $p$ is not constant then $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} p(x)=\infty$, hence there is an $M>0$ such that $p(x)>c$ when $|x|>M$. On the compact interval $[{-M},M]$ the continuous function $p$ assumes a minimum $\alpha=p(\xi)\leq c$. It follows that $p(x)\geq\alpha>0$ for all $x\in{\mathbb R}$.